# configuring reactjs to separate frontend styles from admin styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, frontend

I am using reactjs with a template that I randomly got online to style my project. It works. Now I want to add an admin panel to the website with new styles. Unfortunately, in the styling of the previous template, the body also received some styling. This is overriding the styling of any other template or style that I add for my admin panel. Please is there any efficient way to resolve this styling conflict in my project? I am in a desperate situation right now.

This is how I added the original template css.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/css/main.css">
```

I added it to the public folder and linked it into the html folder.
I tried to add the admin template this way but thats not working right. For now I tried writing basic css in my admin components instead of adding  a template for it. Even that is not having any effect. The template just seems to take over the css of the body.

Comment: Post the code of how the styles are imported in your project

Comment: Thats it up there, i just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The preferance of the styles being loaded greatly depends on the order it is being loaded. So what you have to do it make sure the intial template css is loaded first and your new/custom css is loaded at last. 
 A proper way of dealing with such scenario is to make all the css imports in one file and specify the required order of import in that file.

Comment: Thats the problem, css always clashes no matter the order. I am looking for a better way to load my css without any overrides. I want the css of the custom template to load only for my frontend user and the admin css to load only for the admin user. Nothing should override. Besides, the custom css template even has body styles.